# Having some problems with running Bat files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to learn how to use DeepFaceLab. I downloaded the pre-built package 9.2SSE since I have a i9-9900k and a gtx 1080 on windows 10. after extracting this package. https://mega.nz/#F!b9MzCK4B!zEAG9txu7uaRUjXz9PtBqg 
I attempted to use it as this video tutorial showed.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBax7_UWXvc
However whenever I run the bat files, it opens for a split second then closes. If I run it as an admin i get this error:  [image: error message]

This is the Bat file code:

```
@echo off
call _internal\setenv.bat

"%PYTHON_EXECUTABLE%" "%DFL_ROOT%\main.py" videoed extract-video ^
    --input-file "%WORKSPACE%\data_src.*" ^
    --output-dir "%WORKSPACE%\data_src"

pause
```

The setenv bat file is also in the proper folder from what I can tell. Anyone have any ideas whats going wrong? I tried doing this on my laptop, and all the bat files work fine. But i would prefer to use my desktop since it has a 1080 and my laptop has a 1060

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, Turns out My PATH was messed up. I had some schoolwork last semester that required me to add things to my PATH in order to make it work, now that I have deleted all of the stuff I added to make the work possible it works now!